# How to fix ORA-00905 missing keyword with case expression

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00905

I have problem with `case` in the line I marked it below.

I need it to be shown like

```
debits | credits | total debits | total credits
```

The SQL query is:

```
SELECT cv_amount,
       case when cv_amount > 0 then cv_amount else 0 end as debits, 
       case when cv_amount < 0 then cv_amount*-1 else 0 end as credits,
       sum(case when cv_amount > 0 then cv_amount else 0)--- ERROR SHOWEN HERE--- end as d, 
       sum(case when cv_amount < 0 then cv_amount*-1 else 0) end as c
FROM dof
where currency_code = 368 
  AND to_DATE('05/05/19', 'DD/MM/YY') and to_DATE('05/05/19', 'DD/MM/YY')
group by cv_amount
```

Comment: And **which** exact error is shown? What have you tried to solve it?

Comment: Looks like an Oracle error code. Are you sure you're using MySQL?!?

Comment: Two `case` _expressions_ have no ending `end` keyword.

Comment: why don't you show your expected output and provide some sample data

Comment: Your query seems have some errors: wrong column use for `aggregate functions` for `GROUP BY`, wrong condition in `WHERE` clause (`to_date` part).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a syntax error in the following two lines

```
sum(case when cv_amount > 0 then cv_amount else 0) end as d, 
sum(case when cv_amount < 0 then cv_amount*-1 else 0) end as c
```

the `end` should be with in the parentheses, so the query wil be:

```
sum(case when cv_amount > 0 then cv_amount else 0 end) as d, 
sum(case when cv_amount < 0 then cv_amount*-1 else 0 end) as c
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need `case` for this:

```
select cv_amount,
       greatest(cv_amount, 0) as debits,
       abs(least(cv_amount, 0)) as credits,
       sum(greatest(cv_amount, 0)) as d,
       sum(abs(least(cv_amount, 0))) as c
from dof
where currency_code = 368 and
      <something goes here> = date '2019-05-05'
group by cv_amount;
```

The bigger issues are that the `where` clause doesn't make sense.  And the aggregation by `cv_amount` doesn't really make sense.